# changing color when in portrait mode and below certain viewport width?

Tags: css

I am attempting to change the background-color of a div, but only when both the viewport is under a certain width and also is in portrait mode. So both width and orientation conditions must be met. Can you help please?

Below is my code so far. But it seems only to look if the viewport is in portrait mode and on that condition alone already changes color on the div. If the viewport is in portrait mode, but still above 299px, it should not change color yet. Because it needs to be below 299px and also in portrait mode to do so.

```css
.colorchange-div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 299px) and (orientation:portrait) {
  .colorchange-div {
    background-color: green;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="colorchange-div">

</div>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what has a device width of less than 299px? Do you perhaps mean `max-width` and not `max-device-width`?

Comment: The 299 px is purely for example purposes, @Adam, thanks!  Later will be set for width of smartphones.

Comment: Then you mean to use `max-width` because you are referring to the viewport and not the device, in which case the code works fine.

Comment: Thank you, @Adam!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `max-device-width:` to `max-width:`

like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 299px) and (orientation:portrait) {
  .colorchange-div {
    background-color: green;
  }
}
```

**[Working resizable Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/51q0mp0h/)**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @Syden!! Also for the effort to put it in code and screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of min-device-width, you need to mention max-device-width to work that condition.